# Django - I got TemplateSyntaxError when I try open the admin page. (http://DOMAIN_NAME/admin)

Tags: django, django-grappelli

I use grappelly plugin. When I try open the admin page (/admin) I got TemplateSyntaxError.
It says 'get_generic_relation_list' is invalid block tag.

```
TemplateSyntaxError at /admin/
Invalid block tag: 'get_generic_relation_list', expected 'endblock'
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://DOMAIN_NAME/admin/
Django Version: 1.4
Exception Type: TemplateSyntaxError

Exception Value:    
Invalid block tag: 'get_generic_relation_list', expected 'endblock'
Exception Location: /opt/python27/django/1.4/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py in invalid_block_tag, line 320
Python Executable:  /opt/python27/django/1.4/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.0
Python Path:    
['/home/vhosts/DOMAIN_NAME/httpdocs/media',
 '/home/vhosts/DOMAIN_NAME/private/new_malinnikov/lib',
 '/home/vhosts/DOMAIN_NAME/httpdocs/',
 '/home/vhosts/DOMAIN_NAME/private/new_malinnikov',
 '/home/vhosts/DOMAIN_NAME/private/new_malinnikov',
 '/home/vhosts/DOMAIN_NAME/private',
 '/opt/python27/django/1.4',
 '/home/vhosts/DOMAIN_NAME/httpdocs',
 '/opt/python27/django/1.4/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c12dev_r88846-py2.7.egg',
 '/opt/python27/django/1.4/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-0.8.1-py2.7.egg',
 '/opt/python27/django/1.4/lib/python27.zip',
 '/opt/python27/django/1.4/lib/python2.7',
 '/opt/python27/django/1.4/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2',
 '/opt/python27/django/1.4/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/opt/python27/django/1.4/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/opt/python27/django/1.4/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/opt/python27/lib/python2.7',
 '/opt/python27/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2',
 '/opt/python27/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/opt/python27/django/1.4/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
 '/opt/python27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg',
 '/opt/python27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flup-1.0.3.dev_20100525-py2.7.egg',
 '/opt/python27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv-1.5.1-py2.7.egg',
 '/opt/python27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/SQLAlchemy-0.6.4-py2.7.egg',
 '/opt/python27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/SQLObject-0.14.1-py2.7.egg',
 '/opt/python27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/FormEncode-1.2.3dev-py2.7.egg',
 '/opt/python27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.3-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg',
 '/opt/python27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2-2.2.2-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg',
 '/opt/python27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pysqlite-2.6.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg',
 '/opt/python27/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
 '/opt/python27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL']
Server time:    Вск, 7 Окт 2012 04:19:42 +0700
Error during template rendering
```

In template /home/vhosts/DOMAIN_NAME/httpdocs/templates/grappelli/admin/base.html, error at line 28
Invalid block tag: 'get_generic_relation_list', expected 'endblock'

```
18  <!--[if lt IE 8]>
19  <script src="http://ie7-js.googlecode.com/svn/version/2.0(beta3)/IE8.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
20  <![endif]-->
21  {% block javascripts %}
22      <script type="text/javascript" src="{% admin_media_prefix %}jquery/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
23      <script type="text/javascript" src="{% admin_media_prefix %}js/admin/Bookmarks.js"></script>
24      <script type="text/javascript">
25          // Admin URL
26          var ADMIN_URL = "{% get_admin_url %}";
27          // Generic Relations
28          {% get_generic_relation_list %}
29          // Get Bookmarks
30          $(document).ready(function(){
31              $.ajax({
32                  type: "GET",
33                  url: '{% url grp_bookmark_get %}',
34                  data: "path=" + escape(window.location.pathname + window.location.search),
35                  dataType: "html",
36                  success: function(data){
37                      $('ul#bookmarks').replaceWith(data);
38                  }
```

Comment: What version of grapelli are you running?

Comment: Yeah, thanks, I got it already. I used version 2.4, but I needed version 2.0. How can I describe the problem solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, thanks, I got it already. I used grappelli version 2.4, but I needed version 2.0.